# AFrame Text component does not render with 'logarithmicDepthBuffer=true'

Tags: aframe

When I set `logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;` in the AFrame renderer component, all instances of the `text` component no longer render at all.

To troubleshoot this, I removed all other entities from the scene, the text still did not render. I also tried using the wrapped `<a-text>` component, I tried `alphaTest: 0.5` , setting `depthTest: true` and setting `sortObjects: false` just to see if I could get any kind of result, but found nothing that would produce any results.

```html
<a-scene renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;">
    <a-text value="The quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog"></a-text>
</a-scene>
```

The text does not appear at all. There are no rendering artifacts, or errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [] around renderer

```
<a-scene [renderer]="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;">
    <a-text value="The quick Brown Fox Jumps over the Lazy Dog"></a-text>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been search for the reason why text is always rendered behind other entities independent of their z-indices. Just a naive question: how in god's name do you come to this solution and what was the reason why it didn't work without the square brackets?

Comment: Well, cheered too soon. This solution just causes A-Frame to ignore the renderer settings altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You should make an issue for this on AFrame github. I saw this problem come up for someone else before..

As a workaround, I don't know the specifics of aframe, but can you use the .polygonOffset on the material for the text to avoid the zfighting you were trying to counteract with logarithmicDepthBuffer?

logarithmicDepthBuffer is a cool technique, but when enabled, all shaders that interact with depth have to be aware of it, and some of them aren't written with it in mind.

But if you're trying to fix z-fighting, polygonOffset is one of the more classical solutions.